# object not found when creating targets list programmatically

Tags: targets-r-package

I'm trying to generate a {targets} list programmatically, via a function in an R package.

```
get_pipeline <- function(which_countries) {
  countries <- NULL # avoid R CMD CHECK warning
  print(which_countries) # Shows that which_countries is available
  list(
    targets::tar_target(
      name = countries,
      command = which_countries # But here, which_countries is not found
    )
  )
}
```

The `_targets.R` file looks like this:

```
library(targets)
couns <- c("USA", "GBR")
TargetsQuestions::get_pipeline(couns)
```

I see the following error:

```
> tar_make()
[1] "USA" "GBR"
Error in enexpr(expr) : object 'which_countries' not found
Error in `tar_throw_run()`:
! callr subprocess failed: object 'which_countries' not found
```

Note that the `which_countries` variable is printable, but not found in the call to `tar_target`.

How can I get create the `countries` target successfully so that it contains the vector `c("USA", "GBR")`?

This code is in a GitHub repository at https://github.com/MatthewHeun/TargetsQuestions. To reproduce:

- `git clone https://github.com/MatthewHeun/TargetsQuestions`
- Build the package in RStudio.
- `targets::tar_make()` at the Console.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You could try `command = !!which_countries` instead (powered by tidy evaluation). There's also https://wlandau.github.io/targetopia/contributing.html#target-factories.

Comment: Thanks, Will! Unfortunately, `!!which_countries` gives same error:
```
> tar_make()
[1] "USA" "GBR"
Error in enexpr(expr) : object 'which_countries' not found
Error in `tar_throw_run()`:
! callr subprocess failed: object 'which_countries' not found
Visit https://books.ropensci.org/targets/debugging.html for debugging advice.
```
I'll look at the target factories link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @landau for pointing to  https://wlandau.github.io/targetopia/contributing.html#target-factories which in turn points to the metaprogramming section of Advanced R at https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html.

The solution turned out to be:

```r
get_pipeline <- function(which_countries) {
  list(
    targets::tar_target_raw(
      name = "countries",
      # command = which_countries # which_countries must have length 1
      # command = !!which_countries # invalid argument type
      command = rlang::enexpr(which_countries) # Works
    )
  )
}
```

With `_targets.R` like this:

```r
library(targets)
couns <- c("USA", "GBR")
TargetsQuestions::get_pipeline(couns)
```

the commands `tar_make()` and `tar_read(countries)`, give

```
[1] "USA" "GBR"
```

as expected!